# Escalonar div como imagem

Tags: html, css

Eu estou fazendo uma lista de itens, mas isso tem alguns desafios:

- Responsive;
- O título pode ter mais de uma linha;
- Às vezes eu preciso mostrar um ícone com uma cor de background ao invés da imagem cheia.

Aqui está uma imagem do resultado final esperado:
[image: Resultado final esperado]

E aqui, o que eu já consegui:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  width: 90%;
}
.items::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.items .item {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
}
.items .item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin: 0 2%;
}
.items .item .image {
  background: #eee;
}
.items .item .image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.items .item .image img.icon {
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  width: auto;
}
.items .item .title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
 
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <h4 class="title">Hi. I'm a title.</h4>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" class="icon">
    </div>
    <h4 class="title">Hi. I'm a title.</h4>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <h4 class="title">Hi. I'm a title.</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/caio/pen/ygkfm/

[image: O que eu consegui]

Como você pode ver, eu não consegui definir a mesma escala para a `div` da imagem quando está possui um ícone. Existe alguma solução para o meu problema?

Comment: Você quer fazer isso sem usar @media-query? Eu acho que trabalhar com porcentagem pra responsivo em alguns casos é melhor e fácil de chegar no resultado utilizando css específico pra cada resolução.

Comment: Oi @Mattos, no meu caso precisa ser em porcentagem, mas concordo com o seu ponto.

Comment: Caio, tem [algumas perguntas suas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/336/caio-tarifa?tab=questions) em que nenhuma resposta foi aceita. Se nenhuma resolveu seu problema, é perfeitamente normal deixar em aberto, mas caso alguma delas tenha sido solucionada nas respostas, você pode aceitar para completar o post. Lembrando que, se resolveu de outra forma, pode postar sua solução como resposta para sua própria pergunta e aceitá-la, ajudando futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 1):

dá uma olhada vê se isso é o que você quer:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  width: 90%;
}
.items::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.items .item {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
}
.items .item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin: 0 2%;
}
.items .item .image {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.items .item .image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.items .item .icon-container {
  background: #0f0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.items .item .icon-container .icon {
  margin: auto;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  position: static;
}
.items .item .icon-container .icon img {
  width: 100%;
}
.items .item .title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
 
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <h4 class="title">Hi. I'm a title.</h4>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <div class="icon-container">
      <div class="icon">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h4 class="title">Hi. I'm a title.</h4>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    </div>
    <h4 class="title">Hi. I'm a title.</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/txBzb?editors=111

Um adicional seria colocar `max-height` e `min-height` nas imagens, pra não distorcer demais em resoluções extremas.

Como eu falei no comentário, pense seriamente em utilizar @media queries para tratar propriedades do objeto em diferentes tamanhos de tela.

Comment: Muito obrigado, você chegou bem perto do que eu preciso, mas infelizmente ainda temos diferenças nas alturas. =/

Answer (score 0):

Os tamanhos das `div's` eram proporcionais aos tamanhos das imagens, como as imagens sem o icone era maiores que a mesma as `div's` consequentemente eram maiores, com o `padding` você resolve isso.

```
<a href="#" class="item">
                        // Acrescente o 'style="padding: 18px" ou padding: 7.5%' ;;
    <div class="image" style="padding: 18px">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" class="icon">
    </div>
    <h4 class="title">Hi. I'm a title.</h4>
</a>
```

Um exemplo > [aqui](http://codepen.io/SamirChaves/pen/lpnuH)

Comment: Obrigado, mas sua solução não funcionou como esperado, além de não ser responsive, a diferença de altura entre os itens é enorme.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro:  desvincule a tag "div" de termos como escalonar ou tamanho, div é um elemento de marcação e morre ai seu significado. Propriedades de apresentação pertencem ao CSS.

Segundo: mesmo que você consiga definir em tempo real a largura das imagens isso vai ser muito relativo a onde seu site vai aparecer.

Faça CSS e recorte imagens com dimensões diferentes pra cada tipo de tela exemplos:

celular portrait, celular landscape, tablet, desktop etc.

http://sixrevisions.com/design-showcase-inspiration/responsive-webdesign-examples/

Veja exemplos no link. Nenhum escala imagens.

Ser responsivo significa se adaptar aos inúmeros dispositivos.

Abraço